# zk frozen, column go to mid of listbox when scrolling

Tags: listbox, zk

I have a zul that contain a listbox that i want to freeze the first column of it and i use frozen function to make it freeze.

```
<frozen columns="1" />
```

but the problem is when i try to scroll it, the column that supposed to be freezing is moving to middle of the list box, and that is not looking cool.

[see the 1st column is in the middle of the listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC5NY.png)

here is my zul

tr.z-row td.z-row-inner { border-right: 3px #CCC; }
        
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                            
                        
                        
                            
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                            
                        
                    
                    
                    
                        
                            
                            
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                TOTAL
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                       
                    -->

how can i make the 1st column stick in the left of the listbox? so when i scroll it the other column will move or go missing but my first column stay where it should be.

I'm using zk 6.5.5.

Comment: Could you please narrow down your zul to the minimum you need to reproduce the behavior? That would help others understand the problem. And maybe deleting other parts makes the problem disappear, giving you a better idea of the cause already. Second, is there a specific reason why you use zk 6.5? There is going to be a [massive overhaul of frozen columns](http://blog.zkoss.org/2017/06/20/zk-8-5-preview-smooth-scrolling-in-zk-frozen/) in zk 8.5.

Comment: thank you i have narrow down my zul little by litte, then as you say, i found the problem.  so i just need to delete align=center from                                <div id="appMain" align="center" height="460px" width="99%" style="margin:5px;"> then it stay on the left side. but now my button moving to left side to, may be i have to just add allign center only to the part that i want to be at center. many thanks

Comment: for your question, i need to use zk 6.5 because my team using it too

Answer (score 0):

thank you for Malte Hartwig i have found the solution its because my div with id appmain that has align="center", it has the impact to the listbox ass well, making the column going center when scrolling to the end.

the solution is to add align="left" attribute to my div that contain listbox  so then the list box itself doesn't effected by the center attribute from the upper div.

here is the code

```
<window id="RelationshipResource" border="normal"  width="750px" title="List Detail" 
    closable="true" apply="${arg.controller}">

<scrollview hflex="1" vflex="1">
    <!-- this is the culprit that make my column moving to the center -->
    <div id="appMain" align="center" height="460px" width="99%" style="margin:5px;">
        <div class="centerApp"  height="250px" width="99%">
            <grid>
                <columns >
                    <column label="" width="150px"/>
                    <column label=""/>
                </columns>
                <rows >
                    <row style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                        <label value="Open New Relationship"/>
                        <textbox id="txtOpenNewRelationship" width="200px" />
                    </row>
                    <row style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                        <label value="Item Code" />
                        <textbox id="txtItemCode" width="200px" />
                    </row>
                    <row style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                        <label value="Item Description" />
                        <textbox id="txtItemDescription" width="400px" />
                    </row>
                    <row style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                        <label value="Relationship line" />
                        <textbox id="txtRelationshipLine" width="100px" />
                    </row>
                </rows>
            </grid>

            <!-- here we add align left to make the column not moving -->
            <div class="myTable" align="left" height="110%" >
                <listbox id="listboxSRN"  vflex="1" mold="paging" pageSize="5" pagingPosition="top">
                    <frozen columns="1" />
                    <listhead sizable="true">
                        <listheader label="1st col" width="240px"/>
                        <listheader label="2nd col" width="240px" />
                        <listheader label="3rd col" width="230px"/>
                        <listheader label="4th col" width="230px"/>
                        <listheader label="5th col" width="230px"/>
                        <listheader label="6th col" width="230px"/>
                    </listhead>
                    <listitem >
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                    </listitem>
                    <listitem >
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                    </listitem>
                    <listitem >
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                    </listitem>
                    <listitem >
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                    </listitem>
                    <listitem >
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                    </listitem>
                    <listitem >
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                    </listitem>
                    <listitem >
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                    </listitem>
                    <listitem >
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                        <listcell label="siTamvan" />
                    </listitem>
                    <listfoot style="margin:0px">
                        <listfooter></listfooter>
                        <listfooter align="right">TOTAL</listfooter>
                        <listfooter >
                            <textbox hflex="1" id="txtTotal"/>
                        </listfooter>
                    </listfoot>
                </listbox>
            </div>
            <groupbox id="gb" mold="3d" style="vertical-align:middle;background-color:#FAFAFA;margin-top:2px">
                <button id="btnClose" label="Close" image="/img/Logout24.png" height="40px" width="150px"/>
            </groupbox>   
            <!--<label value="You are using ZK version: ${desktop.webApp.version}"/>--> 
        </div>

    </div>
</scrollview>
```

[here is the picture now the column stick in the left, the paging is going to left too actually because it is part of the listbox,  but the close button still in the middle and i think that's enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIyoL.png)

may be if i want the paging still in the middle like before i have to separate da paging from the list box but i don't think i need that.